# Why doesn't Git detect rename?

Tags: git

Reading around I found that using `git mv` for rename should make Git able to detect the renaming, but in my Git (2.7.4) it doesn't seem to work.

Here is what I ran:

```
 ~ $ mkdir git_tests
 ~ $ cd git_tests/
 ~/git_tests $ git init
Inizializzato un repository Git in /home/git_tests/.git/
 ~/git_tests $ echo "hello" > readme
 ~/git_tests $ git add readme 
 ~/git_tests $ git status
Sul branch master

Commit iniziale

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   readme

 ~/git_tests $ git mv readme leggimi
 ~/git_tests $ git status
Sul branch master

Commit iniziale

Changes to be committed:
  (use "git rm --cached <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   leggimi
```

Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: You need to commit the previous version of the file (`readme`) prior to the git rename detectoin.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you hadn't committed the file yet. `git` only treats renames/file moves differently if the file was already being tracked - in this case, it wasn't, so it'll still treat it as a new file.

Regardless of the move/rename in this case, `readme`/`leggimi` is still a new, untracked file to `git`, so it'll get treated as such.

Answer (score 4):

In complement to the other answers: using `git mv` is not what helps Git detect renames. Git detects them after the fact, using heuristics, so using `git mv old new` or `git rm --cached old; mv old new; git add new` do the same thing.

(Well, not exactly if you have unstaged changes in `old`, i.e. if the file is tracked by has changed not staged in the index. Then `git mv old new` would keep the file tracked and keep the unstaged changes unstaged while `git add new` would stage everything).

Comment: This is a much better answer than Sebastian's. Sebastian's answer suggests new files are a special case for which it just doesn't work. Your answer shows that it works exactly the same for new files as for existing files, and the difference in results is *because* it works exactly the same way.

Comment: Can you be more precise on "not exactly if you have unstaged changes"?

Comment: @antox `git add new` would stage the previously-unstaged changes. `git mv` doesn't do that. (Actually, `git rm --cached old` would be an error already, because `git rm` has a safety check. You'd need `git rm --cached -f old`, by which you're forcibly removing anything you had staged.)

Comment: @hvd I don't understand "`git mv` doesn't do that". `git mv old new` unstages the `old` file and stages the `new` one.

Comment: @antox Try it yourself, when you have unstaged changes to `old`. After `git mv old new`, the staged contents of `new` are the old staged contents of `old`, and the unstaged contents of `new` are the old unstaged contents of `old`.

Comment: Actually, my answer is not "better". In your case, the very reason why you don't see a rename is the reason given by Sebastian. I was just adding a bit more info.